# Longest sub-sequence the elements of which make up a set of increasing integers

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Find the length of the longest continuous sub-sequence of an array the elements of which make up a set of continuous increasing integers.
The input file consists of the number `n`(the number of elements in the array) followed by `n` integers.
example input - 10 1 6 4 5 2 3 8 10 7 7
example output - 6(1 6 4 5 2 3 since they make the set 1 2 3 4 5 6).
I was able to write an algorithm that satisfies `0<n<5000` but in order to get 100 points the algorithm had to work for `0<=n<=50000`.

Comment: Perhaps if you post some code to show what you've tried, people may leave the question open. (Although, since you are asking for a more efficient algorithm, I'm not what you could technically offer more than you already have...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? Arrange the array elements in descending order, each coupled with its index-range as a local maximum (for example, `A[0] = 10` would be the maximum for array indexes, `[0, 10]`, while `A[3] = 4` would be the local maximum for array indexes, `[3,3]`. Now traverse this list and find the longest, continuously descending sequence where the index-ranges are all contained in the starting range.

```
10 1 6 4 5 2 3 8 10 7 7
=> 10, [ 0,10]
    8, [ 1, 7]
    7, [ 9,10]
    6, [ 1, 6] <--
    5, [ 3, 6]    | ranges
    4, [ 3, 3]    | all
    3, [ 5, 6]    | contained
    2, [ 5, 5]    | in [1,6]
    1, [ 1, 1] <--
```

Comment: Well, a very nice solution indeed but having recurrent elements really hurts the algorithm. For example, if after the 5 comes another 5 it gets the algorithm gets quite ambiguous. Or in the a worse scenario what if the array is this - 1 5 4 2 3 7 1 5 4 2 3?

Comment: @DavidAsryan thank you for your comment. Arrange each group of duplicates in an array sorted by their start-indexes. Any duplicates that are candidates for continuation of a term are (1) the next lower number after the term and (2) by virtue of being the next lower number, must either share the same start and end (if they are on the same side of their next higher term) or have mutually exclusive index-ranges as local maxima (as in the case of the 5's as candidates for continuation of 7 in your example, `1 5 4 2 3 7 1 5 4 2 3`).

Comment: @DavidAsryan You might also clarify what is the solution for something like this: `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`.

Comment: Since the problem wants just the length of the subsequence it would be two

Comment: Not to look stupid but I again don't understand how I should handle duplicates. Can you please clarify a bit more.

Comment: @DavidAsryan I don't understand why we are allowed to rearrange the order of 2 and 4 to show a valid sequence in your example, `1 6 4 5 2 3`, and at the same time we are not allowed to rearrange the order of 2 and 4 to show a valid sequence in `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`.

Comment: Anyway, either rule does not adversely affect handling duplicates: if your rule applies then if (1) the duplicate candidates share an index range, according to your rule, the sequence might end there, or (2) if they have exclusive ranges, they either split the current sequence or some are not contained in their predecessor's range. There are no overlapping subproblems: a valid candidate cannot be an exclusive starting term for a sequence since if its range is contained in the parent's, all its valid children's ranges necessarily are as well.

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on the specifics, specifically in terms of time complexity. Ideally in the answer itself rather than the comments. You may be able to traverse the interval list in O(n), but since you have a start and end point, the naive approach would be O(n^2). You explanation of handling duplicates is not clear, especially not how you would implement that or how and whether it would affect time complexity.

Comment: `1 6 4 5 2 3` can be rearranged to form a continuous increasing sequence. `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4` can not. That's why the latter is not a valid subarray.

Comment: @Dukeling thank you for your comments! What's `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4` if not two sequences arranged from `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`?

Comment: @Dukeling I had the idea of binary search on any candidate duplicates, but I do have to give more thought to when duplicates share a range but could affect sequences in different ways, such as with `4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4` vs `4 2 1 1 3 2 3 4`.

Comment: @Dukeling it seems to me that if the duplicates have exclusive ranges the procedure is clear; otherwise, we pick the one that's closer to the parent term, since we know the farther one will necessarily break the sequence at some point.

Comment: @Dukeling (I don't seem to have too many qualms about outlining an idea in an answer and have some elaborations carried on in the comments. In general, I don't think an answer need necessarily be explicit about all its facets and details to provide a possible direction for interlocutors.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן If a sequence is rearranged it needs to be taken as a whole when identifying whether it is a valid answer or not.